# Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables. - Trying to update Database

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, datagridview

The list of problems with my software never seem to end! And once again, it's down to issues with SQL.

Previously, I'd asked on stackoverflow how to perform an inner join query (basically) - see my page for info - and now I have a new issue. I'm trying to update my "Students" database, however every time I do it returns with the error below:

> Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or how I go about fixing it. In my eyes, all I'm doing is trying to update the students table. The "inner join" part was for obtaining classes (see my last post for further clarification: [Syntax Error (Missing Operator) In Query Expression "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457976/syntax-error-missing-operator-in-query-expression))

I've got the code for the relevant areas below:

```
Me.Validate()
Me.myDA.Update(Me.myDataSet.Tables("students"))
Me.myDataSet.AcceptChanges()

MsgBox("Registration Complete.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ASTRAS")

regiattendancedatagripview.Visible = False
reg_complete.Visible = False
reg_merit.Visible = False
reg_referral.Visible = False
reg_viewdetails.Visible = False
```

The above code is meant to update the students database that is being presented to me in a Datagridview. That datagridview has had information passed onto it from the "Classes" database, allowing it to display only the names required in the register. Code below:

```
If attendance_reg_periodComboBox.Text = "" Then

    Else
        Try
            Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\DATA.accdb")
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * 
                 FROM [classes] INNER JOIN [students] ON 
                      classes.StudentForename = students.Forename AND 
                      classes.StudentSurname = students.Surname 
                 WHERE classes.TeacherName ='" & personloggedon.Text & "' 
                   AND classes.Day ='" & System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString & "' 
                   AND classes.Period ='" & attendance_reg_periodComboBox.Text & "'", 
                   con)

            con.Open()
            myDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(myDA)
            myDataSet = New DataSet
            myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "students")
            regiattendancedatagripview.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("students").DefaultView
            con.Close()

            con = Nothing

            If regiattendancedatagripview.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Label7.Visible = True
                regiattendancedatagripview.Visible = False
            Else
                regiattendancedatagripview.Visible = True

                regiattendancedatagripview.Sort(regiattendancedatagripview.Columns(2), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

                reg_complete.Visible = True
                reg_merit.Visible = True
                reg_referral.Visible = True
                reg_viewdetails.Visible = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("An unknown error occured while trying to obtain the class register. Error details below:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "ASTRAS")
        End Try
    End If
```

Essentially - my understanding is that the names from "classes" are being used to search and return a list of names from "students" and so display them in a datagridview. So how come my program can't update the absences column (LastKnownAbsence)?

Comment: DataAdapter Update method works only if you don't have a JOIN in your SELECT statement. But first why are you using a JOIN here? Is it possible that a student exists in a class but not in the students table ?

Comment: Also, never ever concat strings and values to make SQL.  Always use Parameters

Comment: @Steve No- students table has every student on record but class table has students that are in classes ie grouping students into classes

Comment: Then I don't think you need the JOIN. If you remove it the UPDATE should work provided that you have a PrimaryKey set for the "classes" table

Comment: @Steve if you look on my previous post (linked) I’m needing the join because of fetching names from the classes database and matching those names with the names on the students database. What I’m trying to understand is when all the datagridview on my vb form is showing is selected names from the students database - then why is it failing to update as normal? Apologies for vague or unclear questions — I can screenshot the database and update this post if need be?

Comment: I am not sure because I have no way to test your code without the database, but the docs on OldDbDataAdapter.Update method clearly states that you need a single table SELECT command and given the error this probably means that the code of the Update command doesn't look at the fact that you retrieve fields just from the student table. You can try to manually set the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands of the DataAdapter. If even this fails you can build a loop using the DataTable.GetChanges and update every row returned with a manually built OleDbCommand

Comment: @Steve will try that - thanks for your help